# net localgroup add group with spaces and ampersand

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a script that will enable our automated tool to add certain groups into the localgroups of our servers:

net localgroup dbusers A&B /add

The problem I have is that it doesn't seem to like the "&" symbol.

```
C:\>net localgroup dbusers 'A&B' /add
The syntax of this command is:


NET LOCALGROUP [groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
          groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
          groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]

'B' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried single and double quotes and caret without any success.  Can anyone suggest a way to get around this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
C:>net localgroup "administrators" "adom\group012345678901234" /add

The command completed sucessfully

C:>net localgroup "administrators" "adom\group0123456789012345" /add

The syntax of this command is:

NET LOCALGROUP
[groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
              groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
              groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]

C:>
```

Seems net.exe has a problem with long group names. *HATE!*

Comment: Wonderful.  I just discovered this feature.  Looks like net.exe doesn't like usernames that are greater than 25 characters.

Answer (score 5):

I know it sounds crazy, but it's actually because of the length of the group name, not because it has a space. That's why the other people responded saying it worked for them (because the group names they tried weren't as long). I was having the same problem you were, but I found out it was because of the long group name that the "net" command wasn't handling properly. Then I found a utility called "lg" from joeware.net. It worked like a champ. Hopefully this info will help someone else who stumbles on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the Windows Command Prompt, use `^` to escape characters:

```
net localgroup dbusers "aceina\A^&H Support (Accenture)" /add
```

Comment: If I try that i get the following "The syntax of this command is:.."  If I single quote I get "System error 1788 has occurred. The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed".

Answer (score 2):

I just did the following using CMD.EXE from a Windows XP Professional SP2-based machine that is a member of the "DOMAIN" W2K3 Active Directory domain, logged-on with a user account that has both local "Administrator" and "Domain Admin" rights:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\EAnderson>net group "A&B Test" /domain /add
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain ad.tippcity.k12.
oh.us.

The command completed successfully.


C:\Documents and Settings\EAnderson>net localgroup "users" "DOMAIN\A&B Tes
t" /add
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain ad.tippcity.k12.
oh.us.

The command completed successfully.
```

Double quotes look fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old thread but since I had this issue and this was one of the first threads to come up in a Google search, I thought I would add what worked for me:

My goal was to use `net localgroup` to add domain admins to the local administrators group.

I thought the solutions was to use quotes around the "domain\domain admins" part.

Example:

```
c:\> net localgroup administrators "domain\domain admins" /add
```

This failed with the following message:

> There is no such global user or group: “domain\domain.
>
> There is no such global user or group: admins”.
>
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3783.

The real solution was to put the Quotes around the space:

Example:

```
c:\> net localgroup administrators domain\domain" "admins /add
```

This worked for me:
Solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
net localgroup "A&H Support (Accenture)" /add
The command completed successfully.
```

Worked a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll notice that if you use a “net localgroup administrators /add DOMAIN\Group” that the command fails with a syntax error.  Some folks say that this is because of a limitation on the length of the group name, but I call shenanigans on that explanation.  At any rate, you’ll slam your head against your desk for a while, until you do the following:

1) Open up Notepad

2) Paste in the following lines, substituting [DOMAINNAME] and [DOMAINGROUPNAME] as necessary:

Set objLocalGroup = GetObject("WinNT://./Administrators")

Set objADGroup1 = GetObject("WinNT://DOMAINNAME/DOMAINGROUPNAME")

objLocalGroup.Add(objADGroup1.ADsPath)

Set objLocalGroup = Nothing

Set objADGroup = Nothing

3) Go to File > Save As, and save it on your Desktop as “script.vbs”

4) Go to Start and type in cmd, then right-click on cmd and choose “Run as Administrator”:

5) CD to your Desktop and then run the command: “cscript script.vbs” as in the example below, and once the script runs, do a “net localgroup administrators” to verify that the script added the requested group properly:

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just use caret symbol, the below works indeed:

```
C:\>net localgroup dbusers 'A^&B' /add
```

Notice this is specific to the command above, any program launched from cmd can escape characters as he prefers.